# The newly created text file should popup

Tags: file, c#-3.0, console-application, popupwindow

I have a C# console application program that creates a .txt file in the Assembly Path.
is there any way i can make the newly created file popup once the program finishes execution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `Process.Start(fileName);` is what you are looking for.

[Process.Start in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)